# Should I use try/catch statements on lower layers of my WebApi application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, exception

I have a simple WebApi application which represents a user storage. I have DAL and BLL layers. I use `ExceptionFilters` for exceptions handling.

```
public class HandleExceptionsAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly ILogger logger;

        public HandleExceptionsAttribute(ILogger logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            logger.LogError(context.Exception);
        }
    }
```

It writes my exception into a logfile. Should I use try/catch statements on my lower layers (DAL, BLL)? I got an advice to minimize "try catch" clauses as much as possible. I think that I need to thows my exceptions while they don't appear on controller's layer. As i assume it means that I should use try/catch statements into my DAL layer. I should thow up exceptions to BLL layer and thow up exceptions to controller's layer. It looks like this one:

**DAL layer**

```
public class UserRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<User> GetAll()
        {
            IEnumerable<User> users; 

            try
            {
                users = context.GetUsers();
            }
            catch(SomeSpecificException specExc)
            {
                throw specExc;
            }
            catch(Exception exc)
            {
                throw exc;
            }
        }
    }
```

**BLL layer**

```
public class UserService
    {
        public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
        {
            IEnumerable<Users> users;

            try
            {
                users = userRepository.GetAll();
            }
            catch(PreviousSpecificException specExc)
            {
                throw specExc;
            }
            catch(OneMoreSpecificException sExc)
            {
                throw sExc;
            }
            catch(Exception exc)
            {
                throw exc;
            }
        }
    }
```

It looks not good. Can I refuse to use all my try/catch statements and give ExceptionFilters all work?

Comment: Catch-and-release exception handling (catching exceptions just to re-throw them) is a bad idea. At best, the catch clauses are doing nothing. At worst, as here when you write `throw ex;` rather than just `throw;` you're potentially wrecking useful stack trace information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is primarily opinion-based, but you should only handle exception if you have a design need to do so. Logging is a developer need.

I see in one of your comment you want to make "pretty error message". That's totally a design need, but for the UI layer of your program, hence you shouldn't handle the exceptions in your BLL. (well, the real design need is that you don't want your program to crash on the first exception that is thrown, but you get the point)

On the same topic, I'd suggest implementing your logs on the highest layer possible, so you can log well formatted messages as well.

Of course, you can always try/catch in your BLL if you have to, but **rethrow** a new exception, with the original one as its InnerException.

Answer (score 2):

You should apply the try/catch block by following these questions

1. Do you want to "Handle" the exception at specific layer? It means,
   do you want to provide any alternative or any logging etc. when
   exception occurs?
2. Are you the only one who is going to consume this layer? If anyone else can  consume your BAL or DAL, how will he know whether any exception has occurred in your BAL or DAL.

If you don't want to do anything in BAL/DAL when exception occurs, you should not use try catch blocks there. If you want that outer layer should handle the exception, "exception" should come to outer layer and outer layer should have try/catch.

Comment: In my case I want to handle this exception and return response to purpose to handle it on UI and make pretty error message.

Comment: If you don't want to do anything on DAL or BAL layer (for example retrying or logging etc.) You may skip try/catch blocks from DAL/BAL. Handle exception in your controller and play with response accordingly.